# AttributeError: 'Bottle' object has no attribute 'template'

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, bottle

**Example One**

Consider the following:

```
import bottle
import pymongo

application = bottle.Bottle()
@application.route('/')

def index():

    cursor = [ mongodb query here ]

    return application.template('page1',{'dbresult':cursor['content']})
```

Assume that the MongoDB query is correct, and the application is calling the `content` value of `cursor` correctly and passing it to the template which is formatted correctly.

The errors I am getting in the logs are to do with being able to use the `template()` method eg:

```
AttributeError: 'Bottle' object has no attribute 'template'
```

**Example Two**

If I change the corresponding assignment and call to:

```
application = bottle
application.template
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

**Example Three**

If I change the corresponding assignment and call to:

```
application = bottle
@application.route('/')
@application.view('page1.tpl')

return {'dbresult':cursor['content']}
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

**Question**

What is the correct call to the `template()` method to use to get `Example One` working?

Answer (score 1):

To get "Example One" working:

```
return bottle.template('page1',{'dbresult':cursor['content']})
```

`template()` is in the `bottle` module; just reference it as `bottle.template(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

`bottle.template()` isn't a method of the `bottle.Bottle()` application object. It's a function in the `bottle` module.